# Writing new files at intervals in Python 2.x

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, rsync

I currently have a script coded in Python 2.7 which collates a list of variables. This scripts runs on a machine 24 hours a day on a Linux OS.

What I'm looking to do is move the data from these lists to a remote server. This data transfer will be over a 3G internet connection and as such, I'm keen to write the data locally and then transfer the data when a connection becomes available (due to poor coverage etc...)

My intention is, at the start of the code running, to capture the actual time in POSIX and create a new .txt file. I will then calculate 30 minutes after the start time and add this value to a variable also. I intend for my script to check in it's continual loop to check the time. Should it match the 30 minute POSIX value, I will then write all the information from the list to the .txt file before creating a brand new text file and repeating this process over and over again. I will then use RSync to sync the .txt files to a central server.

Is this an efficient way to complete this process? As said, I will be syncing the data to a remote server over mobile internet (3G) and so there may be poor coverage areas. As such, I find it simpler to write the data locally before syncing the files.

I have decided to create files every 30 minutes so that, should the script fail or there be a power loss, only a maximum of 30 minutes worth of data is lost and not hours worth.

I'd like any feedback on my thought process.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? If you've already got a loop, checking the time in that loop will probably have no visible effect on your CPU usage/performance/memory/whatever; why would you expect it to?

Comment: By the way, you almost definitely don't want to check that it _matches_ the time, but rather that it _matches or exceeds_ the time.

Comment: Sorry @abarnert - yes I did mean matches or is greater than. By 'efficient', I was wondering if there was a better way to perform this function of writing to new files at regular intervals other than my proposed way?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you're creating the file, leaving it hanging around empty, then writing a whole list to it, closing it, and uploading it all at once 30 minutes later. If that's true, it would be better to just create the file right before you write it. Or, alternatively, don't maintain a list; just write directly to the file as you go along (maybe calling `flush` every few seconds). Both of those are probably _better_, but neither is more _efficient_ in the usual sense of that term.

Comment: Meanwhile, is there a reason you need the file in the first place? Why do you need to use `rsync`? The major advantage of rsync is that it can handle deltas; for sending completely new files, FTP, HTTP PUT, scp, etc. are all just as good—and they have nice Python wrappers so you can just send to them without having a real file.

Comment: @abarnert The reason I want to create the files is simply so that, should my code be running on a laptop in a non-3G coverage areas for 3 hours, should I embed the data transfer coding into my Python script, it wouldn't transfer the data as there'd be no internet connection. Therefore, I was just going to run RSync as a cron job syncing the files as and when there was a connection

Comment: OK, that's reasonable. You still don't really need rsync (just ftp the files and delete the local copies), but there's no real disadvantage to having the files around since you already want the files around.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no efficiency problem with your design.

You've got a continual loop which is presumably doing some kind of significant work. Adding the cost of getting the current time and doing one float comparison each time through the loop is going to be so cheap by comparison to whatever you're doing that it doesn't make any difference.

If you're *not* doing any significant work most times through the loop, then the loop itself is probably your major performance cost, and you'd be better off just running it less often.

However, it is pretty odd to open the file, leave it sitting around empty for 30 minutes, then write/close/upload it all at once. A better solution would be to just create it right before your write it. Or, even better, write to it as you go along (instead of maintaining the list), maybe flushing it every few seconds, and then close/upload/replace every 30 minutes.

Meanwhile, if the Python code is trying to do something every 30 minutes, and so is your cron job, they'll obviously be out of sync. Since you're expecting it to be potentially hours out of sync anyway because of the 3G problem, this probably isn't a problem.

Finally, what you're doing is pretty close to syslog-style logging and log rotation. Even if it isn't technically a log file in the usual sense, it might still be worth looking at what linux's [`syslog`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) and [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) and/or Python's [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) (in particular, something like [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) or one of the other handlers) can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I'd try to do.

I'd write the data to an output file constantly, flushing every N records. Why lose 30 minutes worth of data to a crash if you can only lose 1 second worth?

Once the file is certain size, or more than 30 minutes elapsed, I'd close the file and move it to `outbound/` directory. Then I'd create a new file as the output file.

A separate script would control the uploads. A crude example:

```
inotifywait -q -m -e create /path/to/outbound | while read fpath cmd fname; do 
  fullpath=$f{fpath}/${fname}
  rsync $f{fullpath} remotehost && rm ${fullpath}
done
```

This will listen to creation events in the outbound directory, so once your scrip has moved a file there, `rsync` will kick in. You may also consider `rsync --remove-source-files` running continuously from cron.